# Where Are Concourse CI Task Outputs Stored

Tags: concourse

I have a Concourse CI task that creates a 100+ GB file that I would like to pass to another task using the task inputs/outputs functionality.  Where do the task outputs get stored between tasks?  Are they stored in the Concourse database or on the worker's filesystem?

Comment: They are stored on the filesystem, as you can see by doing an `ls` in the task. Each input and output are simply directories. If you follow https://concoursetutorial.com/ you will quickly learn how to pass artifacts from one task to another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The outputs from a task are stored on the worker filesystem, and are mounted into the container. If you use that output as an input in a subsequent task *in the same job*, it'll be mounted into that new container as well.